# Are there radiative (QED/QFT) corrections to the Coulomb law?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, coulombs-law

I have heard about the radiative corrections to the Coulomb law which causes the law to be more complicated than 1/r^2. I may have seen such more complicated expressions in the Landau-Lifschitz QED, but one can see such expressions in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9910080 as well - strictly speaking - for the Coulomb potential and not the force. But I guess that the derivation preserves this complication for the force as well.

So, why the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law does not mention such corrections and how its statement about the correction-less Coulomb law

> The law has been tested extensively, and observations have upheld the
> law on the scale from 10^−16 m to 10^8 m.

is compatible with the radiative corrections and the experimental tests of radiative corrections?

Comment: There are definitely corrections. See e.g. equation 7-24 in Itzykson & Zuber's book.

Comment: See the Uehling potential: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uehling_potential